FInd closest matrix RD to A where R and D are orthogonal and diagonal matrices respectively
Given a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ I wish to find the matrices $R$ and $D$ (which are orthonormal and diagonal matrices respectively) where the product $RD$ is as close to $A$ as possible (under an appropriate norm):
$$
   A \approx RD
$$
Of course this must be with respect to some norm; e.g. I wish to find $R$ and $D$ for the following minimization problem:
$$
  \min_{R,D} \| A - RD \|^2
$$
This question poses a similar problem where they use the following norm:
$$
\|C\|:=\sqrt{\text{tr}(C^TC) }.
$$
I am looking for a norm that measures the similarity of transformed points; i.e.
$$
  \min_{R,D} \| A\mathbf{x} - RD \mathbf{x} \|^2 =
  \min_{R,D} \| (A - RD)\mathbf{x}  \|^2
$$
for all $\mathbf{x} \in \Re^3$  (where $\|\cdot \|$ is Euclidean distance). Perhaps it may make more sense to constrain
$\| \mathbf{x} \| = 1.$
What I am actually trying to accomplish is find the best rotation $R$ and (non-uniform) scale matrix $D$ that matches a general $3 \times 3$ transform matrix $A$ for a 3D graphics problem I am trying to solve.

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\h{\tfrac12}
\def\bR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\SVD#1{\op{svd}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\red#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\blue#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\RLR#1{\red{\LR{#1}}}
\def\BLR#1{\blue{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Let's rename $D\to B$ for the diagonal scaling matrix so as not to confuse it with differential operators.
Choosing a Frobenius norm allows us to leverage the Orthogonal Procrustes Problem
$$\eqalign{
\min_R\; \frob{RB-A}^2 \qiq R = UV^T \;\LR{\,{\rm for}\; AB^T = USV^T} \\
}$$
Let's find a Frobenius solution for the diagonal scaling problem
$$\eqalign{
&\min_{B}\;&\h\frob{RB-A}^2 \qq {\sf subject\ to}\;\; B=\Diag b \\
}$$
Calculate the gradient
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \h\LR{RB-A}:\LR{RB-A} \\
d\phi
 &= \h\LR{R\,dB}:\LR{RB-A} \;+\; \h\LR{RB-A}:\LR{R\,dB} \\
 &= \LR{RB-A}:\LR{R\,dB} \\
 &= \LR{B-R^TA}:\Diag{db} \\
 &= \bR{\,b-\diag{R^TA}}:db \\
\grad{\phi}{b} &= b-\diag{R^TA} \\
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero yields a closed-form solution
$$b = \diag{R^TA} \qiq B = I\odot\LR{R^TA} \\ $$
The Diagonal & Procrustes solutions can be used to iteratively solve the combined problem
# create a random problem in Julia
n = 6;
A = randn(n,n);
B = R = E = Matrix(1.0*I, n, n);

norm(R*B-A)
# 6.669417378670792

for k = 1:99
  U,s,V = svd(A*B')
  R = U*V'
  dB = E.*(R'A) - B
  B += dB
  if norm(dB) < 1e-12
     println("converged after $k steps")
     break 
  end
end
# converged after 45 steps

norm(R*B-A)
# 2.7582938824344474


In the derivation above, a colon is used to denote the
$\sf Frobenius$ product, which has the following
algebraic properties
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
B:B &= \frob{B}^2 \qquad \{ {\sf Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{XY}:B &= X:\LR{BY^T} \;=\; Y:\LR{X^TB} \\
}$$

Reading thru this -- I mostly understand. I am not familiar with the : and \odot operators although I think I understand what they do. I am having a little trouble where  d\phi = (B - R^T A) L Diag(db) comes from.

Tested your solution (github: https://tinyurl.com/yc3mfpdz).
For matrices that factor perfectly one iteration suffices. For random matrices with values close to 1 it generally uses all 10 iterations and the error is high. For not-quite perfectly factored matrices (randomly multiple 3 entries by number close to 1) it averages 3.1 iterations and error is low. This seems expected.

I added my own test code to the post. The number of iterations required for convergence appears to be independent of the size of the matrix, and varies between $10\to60$ iterations for random matrices.

For random matrices we can not expect close solution can we? i.e. we can't expect the norm(dB) to be small even for the optimal solution?
